# Get height of element when useState is initially set

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function Collapse(props) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const parentRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div className="collapse">
      <div className="collapse-toggle" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
        {props.label}
      </div>
      <div
        className="collapse-content-parent"
        ref={parentRef}
        style={
          isOpen
            ? {
                height: parentRef.current.scrollHeight + "px",
              }
            : {
                height: "0px",
              }
        }
      >
        <div className="collapse-content">{props.children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Collapse;
```

I have this function to collapse an element, reading the height dynamically.

I want it to begin open, but when the state is set to true initially, I get an error reading the height:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollHeight')
```

I don't understand why this would make a difference to getting the scroll height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, a ref's current is not always valid. Initially it's a `undefined`, only after the `div` is mounted, it'll be assigned the corresponding *DOM* instance. So you normally do this.

```
  parentRef.current ? parentRef.current.scrollHeight + "px" : 'auto'
```

This is just to make sure you don't run into runtime error.

Comment: Thanks this explains it to me but doesn't solve the issue as I can't animate from auto, so need the know the correct height on render

Comment: For that part you need to experiment, i suspect you can't get it working since you are attaching the ref to itself, i normally would expect it's attached on the parent or children. But sorry i'm no expert on this.